# Python float64index to float

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with some pandas dataframes where all elements are of type `Float64Index`.  Everything I try to convert those elements to a simple `float` fail.

I have tried `pandas.to_numeric` and `astype(float)`.

Here is a reproducible dataframe that can be recreated from the following `dict`

```
{0: {44: 492.0, 45: 492.0},
 1: {44: Float64Index([506.76], dtype='float64'),
  45: Float64Index([506.76], dtype='float64')},
 2: {44: Float64Index([516.8952], dtype='float64'),
  45: Float64Index([516.8952], dtype='float64')},
 3: {44: Float64Index([527.233104], dtype='float64'),
  45: Float64Index([527.233104], dtype='float64')},
 4: {44: Float64Index([537.77776608], dtype='float64'),
  45: Float64Index([537.77776608], dtype='float64')}}
```

I would like to have `dtypes` return `float` for all the columns.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem where the real issue that should be solved is constructing the dictionary in a way that avoids `Float64Index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data frame looks a little crazy, but here's a try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0z: {44: 492.0, 45: 492.0},
 1: {44: pd.Float64Index([506.76], dtype='float64'),
  45: pd.Float64Index([506.76], dtype='float64')},
 2: {44: pd.Float64Index([516.8952], dtype='float64'),
  45: pd.Float64Index([516.8952], dtype='float64')},
 3: {44: pd.Float64Index([527.233104], dtype='float64'),
  45: pd.Float64Index([527.233104], dtype='float64')},
 4: {44: pd.Float64Index([537.77776608], dtype='float64'),
  45: pd.Float64Index([537.77776608], dtype='float64')}}
)

df.stack().apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))[0].unstack()
```

Output:

```
        0       1         2           3           4
44  492.0  506.76  516.8952  527.233104  537.777766
45  492.0  506.76  516.8952  527.233104  537.777766
```